# Using `functools.partial` with variable-length arguments in python

Tags: python, lambda, functools

I have the following function with using *args, and a lambda function:

```py
def draw_figures(picture: Picture, *figures: Figure):
    # draws the figures on the picture
    ...

figures = [figure1, figure2, figure3]

draw_fun = lambda new_picture: draw_figures(new_picture, *figures)
```

As you can see, this code produces a `draw_fun` that I can call later, giving it a picture to draw the figures I already selected on it. I was wondering if I could do a similar thing with partial functions:

```py
import functools

draw_fun = functools.partial(draw_figures, *figures)
draw_fun(other_picture)
```

Unfortunately, the latter does not work, because then `draw_figures` will take the first figure as the picture. This is coherent with the python documentation, since in `partial`, positional arguments provided to the new function are appended to the ones provided when defining the partial (check below). Is there a way of achieving what I am trying to do using partial?

```py
# from python doc
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
        newfunc.func = func
        newfunc.args = args
        newfunc.keywords = keywords
        return newfunc
```

Answer (score 0):

There's little benefit to use `*figures` in your original definition in the first place. Change it to

```
# You might want to use something more general for figures than list,
# like collections.abc.Sequence or collections.abc.Iterable
def draw_figures(picture: Picture, figures: list[Figure]):
    ...


figure_list = [figure1, figure2, figure3]

draw_fun = lambda new_picture: draw_figures(new_picture, figure_list)
```

Now you can simply specify the figures as a *keyword* argument when you use `partial`.

```
draw_fun = partial(draw_figures, figures=figure_list)
```

If `draw_figures` is a function whose signature you cannot change, I believe you are out of luck. Anything you would need to do to adapt it would be as much work as just avoiding `partial` in the first place.